# WKInterfaceTable rows - remove round rect

Tags: apple-watch, wkinterfacetable

How to remove the rounded corners which appear in `WKinterfaceTable`rows ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By setting the radius as 0 of the group of row.

Comment: In my case, the buttons have still rounded edges, even if I set the radius property of the group to zero.

What can I do about it?